# linear regression prediction doesn't change when I change the single test data

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have made a linear model using scikitlearn and I want to make a single prediction every time.but when I change my test data prediction doesn't change.what should I do?

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn import preprocessing

X = [[1, 55, 207], [0, 0, 65], [2, 8, 67], [2, 31, 270], [0, 5, 73], [0, 2, 98], [0, 0, 65], [0, 0, 115], [2, 0, 65], [2, 0, 67], [2, 7, 64], [2, 7, 66], [2, 10, 67], [2, 7, 66], [2, 9, 67], [3, 0, 115], [1, 3, 67], [1, 0, 51], [0, 0, 17], [2, 7, 68], [2, 8, 67], [2, 7, 67], [2, 16, 0], [1, 16, 45], [2, 11, 80], [2, 9, 78], [1, 8, 67], [0, 0, 43], [0, 0, 47], [2, 0, 72], [0, 0, 41], [0, 0, 43], [0, 0, 115], [0, 0, 361], [0, 0, 50], [0, 0, 43], [1, 15, 54], [0, 0, 43], [2, 0, 63], [1, 0, 56], [0, 0, 58], [0, 0, 45], [0, 0, 165], [3, 0, 115], [0, 0, 52], [0, 0, 67]]

y = [1690000000, 360000000, 400000000, 4860000000, 460000000, 640000000, 370000000, 1000000000, 360000000, 340000000, 400000000, 390000000, 375000000, 390000000, 375000000, 977500000, 800000000, 331500000, 350000000, 370000000, 370000000, 370000000, 380000000, 185000000, 300000000, 750000000, 301500000, 117000000, 155000000, 310000000, 2170000000, 116000000, 345000000, 1700000000, 287000000, 160000000, 235000000, 217000000, 215000000, 172000000, 312000000, 277000000, 1200000000, 977500000, 240000000, 340000000]


means = list(map(lambda x: sum(x)/float(len(x)), zip(*X)))
new_y = []
for i in range(len(X)):

    new_y.append(np.log(y[i]))
    if X[i][1] == 0:
        X[i][1] = means[1]
    if X[i][2] == 0:
        X[i][2] = means[2]
    if X[i][0] == 0 and X[i][1] < 60:
        X[i][0] = 1
    elif X[i][0] == 0 and X[i][1] < 120:
        X[i][0] =2
    elif  X[i][0] == 0 and X[i][1] > 120:
        X[i][0] = 2.5


X = preprocessing.scale(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, new_y, test_size=0.30, random_state=5)

model = linear_model.Ridge(alpha=0.1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
my_x = [[2, 5, 120]]
my_x = preprocessing.scale(my_x)

prediction = model.predict(my_x)
prediction = np.exp(prediction)
print(int(prediction))
```

output is 385349681 and for my_x = [[2,5,270]],output is also 385349681.
these are the data of 46 houses. y is the price and X include number of rooms, age and area of building.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, so it's hard for us to see where exactly it goes astray. It might be something to do with the order functions get called in. Would you be able to provide the full code?

Comment: sorry, I've just posted the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.it was because of preprocessing on my test data.it makes my_x all zero.

```
my_x = [[2, 5, 120]]
my_x = preprocessing.scale(my_x)
```